# Android 7 is not work in appium

Tags: appium

I'm testing using the `APPIUM 1.6.4` & `Android 7.0`. There is no problem to find `ELEMENT` using `WEBVIEW` in `NATIVE`, but any contents output when I did `getpagesource` in changing to `NATIVE Context` again on same condition. If I go to the previous `ACTIVITY` and come back, the `getpagesource` can come out. Why is it happened?
ps. `Android 5, 6` operate normally. Just in `Android 7`, it is stopped when I did native in `ACTIVITY -> webview -> native`. It stop and can not search the element.

I can see last log--

> [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>
> [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
>
> [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'com.skmc.okcashbag.home_google:id/home_btn' using 'ID' with the >contextId: '' multiple: true
>
> [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=test:id/home_btn]
>
> [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=test:id/home_btn]
>
> [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
>
> [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.skmc.okcashbag.home_google:id/home_btn]
>   [debug] [AndroidDriver] Not cleaning generated files. Add `clearSystemFiles` capability if wanted.
>
> [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
>
> [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'test:id/home_btn' using 'ID' with the contextId: '' multiple: true
>
> [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=com.skmc.okcashbag.home_google:id/home_btn]
>
> [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=test:id/home_btn]
>
> [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
>
> [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] getElements tmp 
>   selector:UiSelector[INSTANCE=0,RESOURCE_ID=com.skmc.okcashbag.home_google:id/home_btn]
>   [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
>   [debug] [BaseDriver] Waited for 2525 ms so far
>
> [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":[]}

Comment: Can you please tell me what are you trying to do and why?

Comment: I testing android automator once of scripts. But it not work at android 7.0